# Bootstrap navbar fetch data and change active tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty common use case where I have a vertical nav bar to the left (with Home, Profile as nav options). By default, Home is `active` (highlighted in blue).

However, when I click on "Profile", I need to fetch /profile page and change the active tab.

I am confused as to how to implement this. I don't want to duplicate the nav bar html tags on all html pages. I want logic in one single html (layout.html).

But having logic in place, makes it difficult to update active tab and fetch content remotely.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

U have the specific event when the tab is active.
Refer http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  alert(target);
  //fetch the data through ajax
});
```